# how do I use AZ CLI to configure Azure MariaDB to enable 'allow access to Azure services'?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cli, mariadb-10.3

I could use the below to add a vnet rule in Azure MariaDB connection security page.

```
az mariadb server vnet-rule create \
--resource-group xxx \
--server-name xxx-mariaDB          \
--name db-to-aks                   \
--subnet $SUBNET_ID                \
--ignore-missing-endpoint
```

but how do I enable the 'allow access to Azure Services' option below with AZ CLI?
thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have tested this in our local environment, it is working fine.

You can use the below cmdlet which will create a new firewall rule on MariaDB Server & it will enable  **Allow access to Azure services**.

```
az mariadb server firewall-rule create --resource-group '<RgName>' --server '<MariaDBServerName>' --name "AllowAllWindowsAzureIps" --start-ip-address 0.0.0.0 --end-ip-address 0.0.0.0
```

**Here is the Sample output for reference:**

[image]

For more information, You can refer to this [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mariadb/howto-manage-firewall-cli#create-a-firewall-rule-on-azure-database-for-mariadb-server) about the creation of firewall rules in the Azure Maria DB Server.